Multiple groups replacemet with re.sub problem
I have this piece of code and I really have no idea why it is not working. I want to replace SOMETHING with NOTHING and delete a line with spaces and 50 in it.
Expected output:
NOTHING
1  1
2345234
abcdefg
foobar
wrwerdfdsf

import re

s = """SOMETHING
1  1
2345234
abcdefg
foobar
    50
wrwerdfdsf"""

repl = {'SOMETHING': 'NOTHING', '    50\n': ''}
n = re.sub(
    r'^(SOMETHING)\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n(    50\n)',
    lambda x: repl[x.group()] if x.group() in repl else x.group(),
    s,
    flags=re.M
)

It replaces nothing. Maybe I need to write something in these brackets of x.group()?

How do you know whether it replaces anything? The code doesn't output any result.

Ok, here is re.subn result ('SOMETHING\n1  1\n2345234\nabcdefg\nfoobar\n    50\nwrwerdfdsf', 0)

This works for me. Do you strictly need the dictionary to manage the replacement terms?
import re

s = """SOMETHING
1  1
2345234
abcdefg
foobar
    50
wrwerdfdsf"""


n = re.sub(
    r'SOMETHING\n((?:.*\n){4})\s*50\n',
    r'NOTHING\n\1',
    s,
    flags=re.M
)

print(n)


No, tried to do without it and failed :) Thanks!

Here is the updated version :
import re

s = """SOMETHING
1  1
2345234
abcdefg
foobar
    50
wrwerdfdsf"""

repl = {'SOMETHING': 'NOTHING', '50': ''}
n = re.sub(r'\s{2}', '',re.sub(r'^.*$', lambda x: repl.get(x.group().strip(), x.group()), s, flags=re.M))
print(n)

At first you need to replace the words and then remove the empty lines from it

But I need the grouping because I need to delete whole line with 50 after exact 5 lines after SOMETHING. This code deletes 50 from every position. I guess it is the case where I should ditch regex and do it with parsing.
